# jquery closure cannot retrieve private variable with DOM object

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, closures

if anyone can help me I am having a problem with closures and retrieving a private variable declared that is a element selected by id using jquery. I have a module like so:

```
var package = package || {};

(function() {
        if(!package.slider)
                package.slider = {};

        function Slider() {
        }

        // --------- /Public Members --------- //
        Slider.prototype = {
            init: function(){
                _setEvents();
            }
        };

        // --------- Public Members --------- //


        // --------- Private Members --------- //
        var shoePreview = $('#shoe-preview');  /*somehow this variable does NOT get recognised even though I have it in the DOM.*/

        function _setEvents(){
            $.subscribe('getAllPerspectives', function(event){ _getAllPerspectives() });
            $.subscribe('showPreview', _show);
            $.subscribe('hidePreview', _hide);
        }

        function _getAllPerspectives(){
            _getAngleShoeImage(helper.getCurrentAngle());
            $.each(constants.angles, function(key, val){
                if(val != helper.getCurrentAngle()){
                    _getAngleShoeImage(val);
                }
            });
        }

        function _getAngleShoeImage(angle){
            var shoeImage = shoePreview;
            shoeImage.html('<p>Hello World</p>');

        }


        var that = new Slider();
        package.slider = that;

    })();
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.each(package, function (key, val){
        val.init();
    });
});
```

Now If you looked in the code, there is a variable called shoePreview, which I assume would not be accessible to anything outside the module.

Now somewhere in the code later I will call some methods which will trigger _getAngleShoeImage where I have variable inside called shoeImage set to the private shoePreview variable.

The problem is that once I try to use jquery's html() call it seems to not recognise what the shoePreview variable is.

I've tested this with substituting var shoeImage = $('#shoe-preview'), then calling html() with the desired markup and it works fine.

This problem is so small but it's driving me nuts. Am I writing the var shoePreview = $('#shoe-preview'); in the wrong way or there's something more to it. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is only one problem:
`(function(){hackhackhack()})()` literally mean - *run the closure*, it means you tried to access DOM before it ready, you just need to setup the var *after* init, not in main function,

```
var package = package || {};

(function() {
    if(!package.slider)
            package.slider = {};

    function Slider() {
    }

    // --------- /Public Members --------- //
    Slider.prototype = {
        init: function(){
            //New function here
            _setVars();
            _setEvents();
        }
    };

    // --------- Public Members --------- //


    // --------- Private Members --------- //
    //make it accessible for other proto functions;
    var shoePreview;

    function _setVars() {
       shoePreview=$('#shoe-preview'); // now it will be set when init() run not when object proto initialised
    }
    function _setEvents(){
        $.subscribe('getAllPerspectives', function(event){ _getAllPerspectives() });
        $.subscribe('showPreview', _show);
        $.subscribe('hidePreview', _hide);
    }

    function _getAllPerspectives(){
        _getAngleShoeImage(helper.getCurrentAngle());
        $.each(constants.angles, function(key, val){
            if(val != helper.getCurrentAngle()){
                _getAngleShoeImage(val);
            }
        });
    }

    function _getAngleShoeImage(angle){
        var shoeImage = shoePreview;
        shoeImage.html('<p>Hello World</p>');

    }


    var that = new Slider();
    package.slider = that;

})();
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.each(package, function (key, val){
        val.init();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks I think that might have done the trick. So after doing that I was able to get an object, however, when I tried to use html() to see what markup was inside, it always seems to return undefined when i try to output it as an alert. It's quite strange. :( Anything that could have gone wrong?

Comment: You're a legend!! :)Thanks for the quick repsonse. I was laughing when you wrote (function(){hackhackhack()})(). Was it just any particular reason you wrote it? Really thanks alot :)

Comment: I think i used [this pattern](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-stash.html) from doc i readed several weeks ago